# Cocos2d Delegate Callback Not Working

Tags: xcode, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

I am in the process of adding facebook to my ios xcode game. I have been following some tutorials and such but I am running into a problem that they didn't, when a user logs on then this method should be called:

```
- (void) loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
```

However this method and the other two methods associated with this one are not being called. This method should be called when a user logs onto facebook using the fb login button. I have implemented the FBLoginViewDelegate in my *.h as shown below:

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <CCScrollLayerDelegate , FBLoginViewDelegate> {}
```

and I have imported the facebook sdk:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

The project is a cocos2d game and this code is all in my main layer. When the user logs on then the first method should be called and then when he/she logs out then another method should be called; but no methods from FBLoginViewDelegate are being called. I think that the cocos2d layer is interfering with the delegate.

Thanks,

Edit 1:

```
//this is were i create the button and set the delegate. I am using the newest fb sdk to do the rest. This is in my *.m.

FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];  
loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
loginview.delegate = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:loginview];
```

Comment: Post the code where you set the delegate and create the facebook controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the delegate to the `openGLView`. This is not equivalent to `HelloWorldLayer`. If you are creating the `FBLoginView` inside `HelloWorldLayer` you need to do

```
loginview.delegate = self;
```

Comment: damit all, thanks man. I made that change and everything worked.